# HTML & CSS - min-height: 100% is not working on my website

Tags: html, css

I am making a website. I want to divide the website into 2 columns of various width, both of the same height. So no matter if the right column has more text or the left, I want them both to be equal in horizontal length.

My code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #003399;
  color: #FFCC00;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-part {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: #FFCC00;
  border-right-width: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.additional-part {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  /* margin-left: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-part">

      <h1>Main text</h1>

    </div>


    <div class="additional-part">

      <h1>Additional text</h1>

      <p>Aaaaa</p>
      <p>Aaaaa</p>
      <p>Aaaaa</p>
      <p>Aaaaa</p>
      <p>Aaaaa</p>
      <p>Aaaaa</p>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Problems:

1. The right column - as seen both with the border-right attribute and "aaaaa" in the left - is running till it finishes its text, then it is abruptly ending and the left column is taking its place instead of being kept to the left side properly as I wish. It wanna two columns of the same size, and currently I have a "box" on the right and "jumping" div on the left which is not keeping to itself.
2. I do not know why, but when I look at the right top-header and left top-header (I'm talking about the main text and additional text elements), they are on two separate levels, the right being lower than the left. I want them to start at the same "height" to be symmetric and nice-looking.

Comment: I understand your question will you like it if I answer it with `grid-box`

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if I know what you are talking about, but any help would surely be welcomed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is `grid-box` which let us to make particular columns and rows and there after insert the contents according to our will it is the best way of making grid layouts

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background: darkcyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-part {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.additional-part {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-part">
    <h1>Main text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="additional-part">
    <h1>Additional text</h1>
    <p>Aaaaa</p>
    <p>Aaaaa</p>
    <p>Aaaaa</p>
    <p>Aaaaa</p>
    <p>Aaaaa</p>
    <p>Aaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

100% is 100% of parent element (body), but body is adapting it's size to its children. You should use `min-height: 100vh` instead.

Also, don't use float for anything but images and "blurbs" in text. In this case, I would use `display: flex` instead to position your elements.

Comment: Please set this answer as the correct one, if that's the case. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4 < no you can use .row and .col

otherwise, try this

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.main-part, .additional-part {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #003399;
  color: #FFCC00;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.column-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main-part {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: #FFCC00;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.additional-part {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="column-container">
  
      <div class="main-part">

        <h1>Main text</h1>

      </div>


      <div class="additional-part">

        <h1>Additional text</h1>

        <p>Aaaaa</p>
        <p>Aaaaa</p>
        <p>Aaaaa</p>
        <p>Aaaaa</p>
        <p>Aaaaa</p>
        <p>Aaaaa</p>

      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Option 1:
If you are using bootstrap 4, you can simply fix this using `.container` , `.row` , `.col` combinations.

Option 2:
You can fix this issue with this code. I have added a div for wrapping column `div` (`.container` is a commonly used class.). And using `display: flex;` css property.
Note: No need for `min-height: 100%;`.

Just replace with this code. Good luck!